# incorrect status code displayed in password guessing attack using burp suite

Tags: penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

would anyone please take a look at the image of my burp suite result. I am learning how to brute force password guessing attack for penetration testing subject. Assuming `test` and `test` is the correct username and password, but as attacker they do not know it. So, when attempting brute force, it should display `302` status code instead of `200`. I understand that `200` would means *"username and password does not match"*. And `302` would means it matches, so how is it that my result shows all in contrast?

I should be expecting to get `302` for the request i have labeled in red, right? While the other requests should all be `200`?

[Burp Suite Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7sWg.png)

Comment: You have it backwards. The `200` statuscode means OK. The `302` statuscode is a temporary redirect. Most likely back to the same logon page because the logon failed.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers  Meaning my brute force did actually detected the correct username and password by showing statuscode `200 OK` ?

Comment: Yes, likely. Try them and see for yourself 

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Got it! Thank you so much ! ;)